# Adding Dimmer to Fan Light

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, ceiling-fan, dimmer-switch

I'm looking to add a dimmer switch to the lights on my ceiling fan and have the fan part of it work by pulling the chain. The ceiling fan is pretty standard, 4-wire as shown below. Is the following an acceptable approach to connect the dimmer to the light?

[image: Fan Dimmer Connection Diagram]
https://www.protoolreviews.com/wiring-connecting-ceiling-fan/

Everywhere I read, people say not to connect a dimmer to a ceiling fan (maybe they just mean the motor). The only thing I can think of is the fan and light now share the same return path, but that shouldn't be an issue, correct?

In the end I plan on connecting some recessed lighting to the ceiling fan light, but I wanted to keep this question simpler and to the point.

Comment: If the switch is new work install a three conductor cable, code requires neutral at new switch locations. or a 4 conductor (4 + earth)  if you may want a wall mouted fan control in the future. (if you're just upgrading an existing switch you don't need to replace the existing cable)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, just replacing an existing switch and I don't plan on replacing the cable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You're fine, don't worry about it

The reason why people say "don't connect a dimmer to a ceiling fan" is as you suspect -- they're talking about hooking a dimmer up to a ceiling fan's motor, which makes for both an unhappy dimmer and an unhappy motor.  (You need a special *fan speed controller* instead.)  With separate hots to the fan and light, as you describe, you are free to put whatever sort of control fanciness you wish on the light without affecting the fan.